# Google Map with Android Application

Tags: android

I want to know about the configuing process of Google Map in an Android Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To program maps , you need to donwload the Google Add ons API . Then create a project in eclipse(hope u r using that) on Android and select the Google Addons API 1.x / 2.x version that u downloaded.

You need to obtain an API key using your debug.keystore file . (this exists in the folders of your installation) .First step is to obtain a local key(lets say) using that file.Then you need to obtain the mapsAPI key for that given localkey online. You can check google for that.(I dont remember the loc.) .
INclude the key in the android.xml file with the value android:mapsAPIKey = "key obtained".

Extend MapActivity and overide isRouteDisplayed() . This should give you a basic idea...i hope ..

Hope this helps ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Maps aren't baked in to Android.  You'll need to download the [external library](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing.html) and [obtain an API key](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html).